Ansible connection to windows server error 403
I'm trying to execute a playbook from Ansible Tower that will do some things on a windows server and as a first task it 'gathering facts' and it is already failing at that point with error code 403.
Error message looks like this (port and connection type is different in some cases as I tested multiple scenarios):
basic: Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 403
Tested in other ansible template in tower, connection to port 5985, 5986 is working and ping also working fine to the target machine.
Current winrm configuration on target machines allows everything (as I was running out of ideas what can be the issue here.
Client config:
Client
    NetworkDelayms = 5000
    URLPrefix = wsman
    AllowUnencrypted = true
    Auth
        Basic = true
        Digest = true
        Kerberos = true
        Negotiate = true
        Certificate = true
        CredSSP = true
    DefaultPorts
        HTTP = 5985
        HTTPS = 5986
    TrustedHosts = *

Service config:
Service
    RootSDDL = O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GR;;;IU)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GXGW;;;WD)
    MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
    MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 1500
    EnumerationTimeoutms = 240000
    MaxConnections = 300
    MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds = 120
    AllowUnencrypted = true
    Auth
        Basic = true
        Kerberos = true
        Negotiate = true
        Certificate = true
        CredSSP = true
        CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed
    DefaultPorts
        HTTP = 5985
        HTTPS = 5986
    IPv4Filter = *
    IPv6Filter = *
    EnableCompatibilityHttpListener = true
    EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener = false
    CertificateThumbprint
    AllowRemoteAccess = true

The Ansible Tower servers are in different network than the target machine, not sure if that requires additional setups on the target machine to allow this connection.
Also on target machine there isn't any policy configured that would affect the above settings.
I tried with multiple setups. On the ansible Tower host variables we added the following variables:
ipaddress: 1.1.1.1
ansible_host: 1.1.1.1
ostype: "windows"
ansible_user: "user"
ansible_password: "password"
ansible_connection: "winrm"
ansible_winrm_transport: "ntlm"
ansible_port: 5986
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: "ignore"

also tried with port 5985 and with winrm_transport "basic" all failing with error code 403.
Can anyone guide me in some direction which can still cause this issue?
Also let me add that other software in the same network where the target machine is able to use wsman to connect to the server, hence I'm thinking that probably there are still some restrictions on the system, which I'm not aware of.
